# How to extract from sheet a, multiply by a factor in sheet b and paste in sheet c while including preceding data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

im trying to figure out a way to automate this process. I've broken it down in to the following steps but don't know how to start.. VBA code is a slight edit from record macro. Any guidance would be really appreciated!

1) Check how many cities starting in current month in 'Launch Matrix tab', [image: this]

2) Extract data from 'sample data tab', [image: this]

3) multiply (2)'s data with the amount of cities starting, in order to see full impact of X amount of cities

4) and paste in 'Consolidated Tab' under the right month [image: tab]

Consolidated tab looks exactly the same as the sample data tab, only difference is it shows a consolidated view.

Code for first 2 months looks like the following:

```
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=('Launch Matrix'!R2C4*'Small City Data'!R[-1]C+'Launch Matrix'!R3C4*'Medium City Data'!R[-1]C+'Launch Matrix'!R4C4*'Large City Data'!R[-1]C)"
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range("L5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range("D5:L5").Select
    Range("L5").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=('Launch Matrix'!R2C4*'Small City Data'!R[-1]C+'Launch Matrix'!R3C4*'Medium City Data'!R[-1]C+'Launch Matrix'!R4C4*'Large City Data'!R[-1]C)+('Launch Matrix'!R2C5*'Small City Data'!R[-1]C[-1]+'Launch Matrix'!R3C5*'Medium City Data'!R[-1]C[-1]+'Launch Matrix'!R4C5*'Large City Data'!R[-1]C[-1])"
    Range("D5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I want Feb-20 in consolidated tab to include launches in Feb-20 (i.e. Month 1 rev/costs * # of launches in Feb-20) and Month 2 data of Jan-20 launches (Month 2 rev/costs * # of launches in Jan-20) and so on and so forth.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you illustrate your expected results please?

Comment: @SJR this is with all small, medium and large city active ![this](https://i.imgur.com/5fMoNS2.png) and with only small city active ![this](https://i.imgur.com/ybesiuJ.png)

Comment: @SJR also [this](https://i.imgur.com/TBBCb0W.png)

Comment: So you have a working formula? Why the need for VBA? Isn't it just a case of inserting the same formula into a range of cells in your consolidated sheet?

Comment: There are 50 launch months, my formula just goes till 3 months. and it's too manual to add prior months data, then add current month data as you can see from my post 22mins ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to simulate your whole set-up so here is a slimmed-down example which should give you some pointers.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) is worth a read.

```
Sub x()

Dim rLaunch As Range, c As Long

'table showing monthly totals of small etc
Set rLaunch = Worksheets("Launch").Range("C2").CurrentRegion
'remove headings so just have numbers
Set rLaunch = rLaunch.Offset(, 2).Resize(, rLaunch.Columns.Count - 2)

'loop through each column of table (months)
For c = 1 To rLaunch.Columns.Count
    'revenue
    'multiply small number by small revenue and add to same for medium and large
    Worksheets("Consolidated").Range("A3").Offset(, c).Value = _
        rLaunch(1, c) * Worksheets("Small").Range("B4").Offset(, c) + _
        rLaunch(2, c) * Worksheets("Medium").Range("B4").Offset(, c) + _
        rLaunch(3, c) * Worksheets("Large").Range("B4").Offset(, c)
Next c

End Sub
```

**Launch sheet**

[image]

**Small city sheet** (medium and large are the same)
[image]

**Consolidated sheet**

[image]

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY HOW IT SHOULD BE WORKINGGGG! Could you please provide a comment as to what each line does, so i can replicate and expand it for my whole set up?

Comment: What does this line do: Set rLaunch = rLaunch.Offset(, 2).Resize(, rLaunch.Columns.Count - 2)

Comment: Have added a few comments. That removes the extraneous columns so you just have the table of numbers D2:I4 and none of the headings. The rest just loops through each column of the table and multiplies each number by respective sheet revenue. Perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: It's working but im encountering an issue. Where a month doesnt have a launch, it just shows zero rather than continuing prior months data?

Comment: A zero in the consolidated sheet? Why should it continue the prior month?